# How to get a value in a foreach loop into a sum?

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a variable in a `foreach` loop as seen in the following snippet that calculates a user's home folder size in MB:

```
$TotalColItems = @()
foreach ($user in $ListofUsers)
{
    $colItems = (Get-ChildItem $user.HomeDirectory -Recurse |
                Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum)
    Write-Host "`r`n Size of:" $user.HomeDirectory
    "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.Sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    $Calculation = "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.Sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    $TotalColItems += $colItems.Sum
    $user.HomeDirectory + " = " + $Calculation | Out-File $LogFileName -Append
    Remove-Item $user.HomeDirectory -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-Host "`r`n Removed HomeDirectory: " $user.HomeDirectory
    Write-Host "`r`n Verifying you want to remove the user: " $user.Name -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Red
    Write-Host "`r`n"
    Remove-ADObject $user.DistinguishedName
    Write-Host $TotalColItems
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to get a total value of all `$colItems` that I can then calculate MB off of.

I tried putting this in the loop:

```
$TotalColItems += $colItems
```

but it resets itself per loop, so it doesn't keep a running appended total.

How can I get the `$colItems` variable per loop to append their value to a variable so that I can have a sum total of all the user directory sizes?

Comment: `$TotalColItems += $colItems` -> `$TotalColItems += $colItems.Sum`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - so that sort of works, but I end up with something like: 4199 155090 5095095...so 3 values in the variable instead of a running total.

Comment: Start by assigning `0` to `$TotalColItems` - you've assigned an empty array to it, so it will act like an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$TotalColItems` variable in your example is initialized as an *array* (`@()` is the array subexpression operator), so it acts like one. Initialize it as a number and you'll find it works as expected (renamed variable names for self-explanatoryness):

```
$TotalHomeDirSizeMB = 0
foreach ($user in $ListofUsers)
{
    # Calculate sum of file sizes, grab Sum property value directly
    $HomeDirSize = (Get-ChildItem $user.HomeDirectory -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property length -sum).Sum

    # Calculate and store size in MB
    $HomeDirSizeMB = $HomeDirSize / 1MB
    # Add to cumulative size variable
    $TotalHomeDirSizeMB += $HomeDirSizeMB

    # Write results to screen + file    
    Write-Host "`r`n Size of: $($user.HomeDirectory)"
    Write-Host ("{0:N2} MB" -f $HomeDirSizeMB)
    "$($user.HomeDirectory) = $HomeDirSizeMB MB" | Out-File $LogFileName -Append

    # Remove home directory
    Remove-Item $user.HomeDirectory -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-Host "`r`n Removed HomeDirectory: " $user.HomeDirectory

    # Wait for user to verify deletion from AD, preempt Confirmation if verified
    Write-Host "`r`n Verifying you want to remove the user: " $user.Name -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Red
    if((Read-Host -Prompt "y for yes") -eq 'y'){
        Remove-ADObject $user.DistinguishedName -Confirm:$false
    }
}

# Write cumulative size to screen
Write-Host "Removed $TotalHomeDirSizeMB MB"
```

Comment: Thank you sir...much appreciated!  it also helps me learn to see the code simplified.

Comment: quick question...is there ever a time when a variable and its value that was in a foreach loop won't be available outside of that loop?  Can I reference it at any time after it was first declared and a value written to it?  I guess I'm confused when Mike below references a global variable instead...

Comment: In your example everything is in the same scope, any variable written to inside the loop will still be accessible outside

Comment: @TheCleaner [Check this out](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/a069eb46a53bc0f0ec69addfec7e0840)

Comment: Quick edit if you will (I don't have enough points)... $HomeDirSizeMB = "{0:N2}" -f ($HomeDirSize / 1MB) -- that works better to keep it at 2 decimal places...otherwise I end up with it out to the 8th decimal place.

Comment: Thank you for the link...that helps me understand it

Comment: @TheCleaner `-f` turns the number into a string, I prefer to not convert things to strings until I have to actually present them. `Write-Host ('Removed {0:N2} MB' -f $HomeDirSize)` instead

Comment: I see, so I should change it later in my script where I write to the log as well...so this: `"Total User Folder Cleanup =" + $TotalHomeDirSizeMB + " MB" | Out-File $LogFileName -Append` - becomes `"Total User Folder Cleanup =" + ({0:N2} -f $TotalHomeDirSizeMB) + " MB" | Out-File $LogFileName -Append`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128655/discussion-between-mathias-r-jessen-and-thecleaner).

Answer (score 1):

Couple of different ways you can achieve what you are looking for, however the easiest is probably to declare `$TotalColItems` as a Global variable before starting your foreach loop and then incrementing like you have been.  so just a `Global:TotalColItems = 0` and then changing the incrementer to `Global:TotalColItems += $colItems`  If that does not work for you can you post up your full foreach loop for us to take a look at?

Comment: edited question with the full "foreach" loop.  The final "write-host" is just so I can see what the value is for now...I'm not a coder by trade so this looks pretty crappy in general I'm sure.

Comment: Well it looks like Mathias beat me to it but I already wrote the comment so.. it looks like the problem is that you are creating `$TotalColItems` as an empty array, you need to set it equal to 0 instead so that it will keep adding to the sum rather than build an array of all of the values.

Answer (score -1):

```
$obj = New-Object PSObject {
Collection = "" 
}

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $user.HomeDirectory -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property length -sum)
Write-Host "`r`n Size of:" $user.HomeDirectory
"{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
$Calculation = "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

Foreach($item in $ColItems) 
{
$obj.Collection = $Item
}
```

Did Not test this but I think it should work....

Comment: $colItems is only a single value inside the original foreach.  I don't think there would be multiple $item in it to run against...unless I'm missing something.