# How to ignore null values in a foreach in powershell?

Tags: powershell, foreach, null

Follow up to this question: [How to get a value in a foreach loop into a sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728856/how-to-get-a-value-in-a-foreach-loop-into-a-sum)

I have this snippet of Powershell code:

```
$TotalHomeDirSizeMB = 0
foreach ($user in $ListofUsers)
{
    # Calculate sum of file sizes, grab Sum property value directly
    $HomeDirSize = (Get-ChildItem $user.HomeDirectory -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property length -sum).Sum

    # Calculate and store size in MB
    $HomeDirSizeMB = "{0:N2}" -f ($HomeDirSize / 1MB)
    # Add to cumulative size variable
    $TotalHomeDirSizeMB += $HomeDirSizeMB

    # Write results to screen + file  
    Write-Host "`r`n Size of:" $user.HomeDirectory
    Write-Host ("{0:N2} MB" -f $HomeDirSizeMB)
    "$($user.HomeDirectory) = $HomeDirSizeMB MB" | Out-File $LogFileName -Append

    # Remove Home Directory
    Remove-Item $user.HomeDirectory -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-Host "`r`n Removed HomeDirectory: " $user.HomeDirectory

    # Wait for user to verify deletion from AD, preempt Confirmation if verified
    Write-Host "`r`n Verifying you want to remove the user: " $user.Name -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Red
    if ((Read-Host -Prompt "y for yes") -eq 'y'){
        Remove-ADObject $user.DistinguishedName -Confirm:$false
    }
}
Write-Host "Removed $TotalHomeDirSizeMB MB"
```

I need a way to deal with the script not erroring out if the user's homedirectory is NULL in this AD attribute.

I thought it would be an embedded IF statement below the foreach, but I can't get the If statement work properly, I keep getting syntax errors.

Can anyone assist on what the IF statement would be to make sure the foreach code runs only if the HomeDirectory has a value?

Comment: Hi, please show us your attempt with the `if` block (edit your question), it is fairly easy, you' have help very soon.

Comment: @sodawillow - I was doing if {$_.HomeDirectory -ne $null} but it would error out still if the attribute was blank...not sure why

Comment: You need parens `()` instead of curly brackets `{}`

Comment: doh!  Thank you sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
$TotalHomeDirSizeMB = 0
foreach ($user in $ListofUsers)
{
    if ($user.HomeDirectory) {
        # Calculate sum of file sizes, grab Sum property value directly
        $HomeDirSize = (Get-ChildItem $user.HomeDirectory -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property length -sum).Sum

        # Calculate and store size in MB
        $HomeDirSizeMB = "{0:N2}" -f ($HomeDirSize / 1MB)
        # Add to cumulative size variable
        $TotalHomeDirSizeMB += $HomeDirSizeMB

        # Write results to screen + file  
        Write-Host "`r`n Size of:" $user.HomeDirectory
        Write-Host ("{0:N2} MB" -f $HomeDirSizeMB)
        "$($user.HomeDirectory) = $HomeDirSizeMB MB" | Out-File $LogFileName -Append

        # Remove Home Directory
        Remove-Item $user.HomeDirectory -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Write-Host "`r`n Removed HomeDirectory: " $user.HomeDirectory
    }

    # Wait for user to verify deletion from AD, preempt Confirmation if verified
    Write-Host "`r`n Verifying you want to remove the user: " $user.Name -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Red
    if ((Read-Host -Prompt "y for yes") -eq 'y'){
        Remove-ADObject $user.DistinguishedName -Confirm:$false
    }
}
Write-Host "Removed $TotalHomeDirSizeMB MB"
```

Answer (score 4):

I personally like to pre-filter, such that you do not have to evaluate during each pass using *if*. I find this to be more easily readable/succinct, and also keeps the code from heading towards the "[pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming))".

This works if all of the code within the loop is dependent only on this single attribute being set (and those without it you are uninterested in).

```
$FilteredListOfUsers = $ListofUsers | ?{$_.HomeDirectory -ne $null}
foreach ($user in $FilteredListOfUsers) { #do work...}
```

That being said, the first responder's work is equally correct.

Comment: You should also just be able to wrap the 1st line in parenthesis instead of assigning to a variable and pipe `|` to for-each

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($user in $ListofUsers)
{
    if ($user.HomeDirectory) {
        your original code
    }
}
```

This will check if `$user.HomeDirectory` is not `$null`

Comment: Hi, this will output errors if `$user.HomeDirectory` is `$null` as OP wants. You'd have to test `$user.HomeDirectory`instead.

Comment: i thought he wanted to check the response from gci

Comment: _if the user's homedirectory is NULL in this AD attribute_